# Using Python parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator to populate values in one field based on those in another?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, field-calculator, query

I am trying to populate a field with a sorting code that represents the value of another field. Example:

```
 EXPCODE|SORT|
 S4DNN2 |3.5
 H2BNN2  5.0
```

EXPCODE is a field with a value like "S4DNN2." SORT is a field that needs to represent the EXPCODE with a numerical value. What would I use for Python code to automatically populate the SORT field? I started with a simple "if" statement, but can't quite figure it out.

```
def EXPCODE(field_value):

    if field_value = "S4DNN2"
        return field_value "3.5"

    if field_value = "H2BNN2"
        return field_value "5.0"
```

The EXPCODE values I show are examples, I have about 67 different ones with unique numerical values that need to be populated in "SORT"

Any ideas?

Update: I am trying to execute this with the field calculator with use of the python parser

Comment: Would you be able to **edit** your question to make clear whether you are trying to do this using the Python parser of the Field Calculator in ArcGIS for Desktop, please?  There are many [Q&As here about this topic](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python+field-calculator) so I suspect your question will be a duplicate of one or more of them.

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
def EXPCODE(field_value):

    if field_value = "S4DNN2"
        return field_value "3.5"

    if field_value = "H2BNN2"
        return field_value "5.0"
```

should probably be:

```
def EXPCODE(field_value):   
    if field_value == "S4DNN2":
        return 3.5  
    elif field_value == "H2BNN2":
        return 5.0
```

but if this is coming from the Field Calculator there may be more details that you need to provide before this will work for you.

Comment: I tried your solution, but didn't have any success, just a syntax error in the results window. I read another post where you suggested to someone that they import there shapefile into a geodatabase for better results. I tried this also without any help. Any more ideas? Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Just a thought, the EXPCODE field is a text string while SORT is a double, would that make a difference?

Comment: Could you **edit** your question to include the exact code you ran with the precise syntax error that you received, please?

Comment: If these values are being returned to a field which is a Double then the quotes should not be included. I'll try to update my answer when I am on my laptop rather than iPhone.

Comment: The code I ran was exactly how you suggested, both with and without quotes:                                                        def EXPCODE(field_value):   
    if field_value == "S4DNN2":
        return "3.5"  
    elif field_value == "H2BNN2":
        return "5.0"                                                                     The error was "000539: Error message from Python. The calculation used by the Calculate Field or Calculate Value tool is invalid"

Comment: Are you using the Python parser on every test? What precisely are you entering as the Expression?  What precisely is the syntax error that you mentioned?  Please **edit** your question to address any requested clarifications such as these.  The reason for me suggesting that you do it that way is elaborated upon at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353